# I have a problem with a list in html and css

Tags: html, css, list

How could I make the number 10 separate from the text "millonario" in css
my code html

```html
<tr class="millonario">
  <td>
    <ul>
      <li>
        1.<img src="../imagenes/Equipos/millonarios.png">Millonarios
      </li>
    </ul>
  </td>
  <td class="fila-1">10</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>23</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean "separate from the text"?

Comment: What are you actually intending to do? Putting a list inside a table seems to me as either a wrong use of a table or a wrong use of a list.